# Unexpected error communicating with Stripe, errno 55

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Billing with stripe, I have a form and when I submit information and place the order, the following error has occured:

```
Unexpected error communicating with Stripe. If this problem persists, let us know at support@stripe.com. (Network error [errno 55]: Failed sending HTTP POST request)
```

My PHP code is this :

```
  <?php
    require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
    
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(' 
    sk_test_51Gw3j3DiiBRVUNG3QmcK0fjrBkpc31k5bqkX5tP3L5zo4GkLysZEO7iyflCHGoIAa6XtRJMiWjB0inTbZF390JiS00gtV1CREh
    ');

    $POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];  
    
    echo $token . '<br>';
    echo $first_name . '<br>';
    echo $last_name . '<br>'; 
    echo $email . '<br>';  

    \Stripe\Stripe::setVerifySslCerts(false);

    try {
        $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
            "email" => $email, 
            "source" => $token
        ));
    
        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => 5000, 
            "currency" => "usd", 
            "description" => "porn video", 
            "customer" => $customer->id
        ));
    
        print_r($charge);   
    } catch (Exception $s){
        echo $s->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

And the output as follows:

[image: Output of the code above]

I have installed the SSL certificate.

[image: Mozilla Certificate]

I'm using Wampserver with PHP 7.3.12 and Apache 2.4.41
.

Comment: Please don't post text as image. Make sure all textual content is included as text within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing SSL on the localhost is extremely pointless; use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) instead.